# Hawthorne effect in clinical research, definition and advice for non-parallel designs

Tags: multilevel-analysis, clinical-trials

Hawthorne effect is simply described as a bias in performance as a consequence of being under observation. Its namesake was a study of workers, where researchers specifically noted a *positive* performance bias. I suppose the general term "Hawthorne effect" could also be taken to indicate a negative performance bias, like test anxiety. Either way, researchers seem to recommend that Hawthorne effect is prevalent and enrolling a parallel control arm is a way of handling it.

However, I don't feel completely confident in this explanation. If we were to rigorously state *what* the Hawthorne effect is in a model, the understanding would be something like a fixed effect where

$$E[\mbox{Response} | \mbox{Treatment}, \mbox{Observation}] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \mbox{Treatment} + \beta_2 \mbox{Observation}$$

and since observation is fixed and completely balanced, it's aliased with the intercept $\beta_0$ which we omit from interpretation. The implication is that 1) the study data does not appropriately predict the response as a consequence of the bias but 2) $\beta_1$ estimates the unbiased treatment difference.

This brings two problems to mind:

1) What if $\mbox{Observation}$ were a function of time?

2) What if $\mbox{Observation}$ interacted with treatment?

Has anyone formalized these concepts for clinical research? Are there sensitivity analyses that can address the problem? What happens with non-parallel designs like stepped wedge or cross-over designs? What about imbalanced designs? What would be the effect of adjusting for cumulative duration under treatment in a longitudinal design with many sampling periods?